# SQL - Help left join query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, left-join

I'm trying get datas using an only query but i can't get what i want.
I've got 3 tables : 
I would like to get all photos datas with their max step (id and name).
If they don't have it, a null value is ok.

```
Photo table

photo_id | photo_name
---------------------
1        | A 
2        | B 
3        | C 
4        | D 
5        | E 

Steps table

step_id | step_name  
----------------------
1       | AAA         
2       | BBB         
3       | CCC        
4       | DDD   

photoStep table

id | photo_id | step_id
----------------------
1  | 1        | 1         
2  | 1        | 2         
3  | 1        | 3        
4  | 3        | 1
5  | 5        | 1
```

The result that I would like to have is that

```
photo_id | photo_name | step_id | step_name
-------------------------------------------
1        | A          | 3       | CCC  
2        | B          | NULL    | NULL 
3        | C          | 1       | AAA  
4        | D          | NULL    | NULL 
5        | E          | 1       | AAA
```

I've tried this query but it misses something because too many lines :

```
SELECT * FROM photo p
LEFT JOIN photoStep ps ON ps.photo_id=p.photo_id
```

I've got this kind of results :

```
photo_id | photo_name | step_id | step_name
-------------------------------------------
1        | A          | 1       | AAA  
1        | A          | 2       | BBB  
1        | A          | 3       | CCC  
2        | B          | NULL    | NULL 
3        | C          | 1       | AAA  
4        | D          | NULL    | NULL 
5        | E          | 1       | AAA
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This type of problem is called "Max in group". Google that and you'll find a lot of different approaches to solving your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a `LEFT JOIN` on `MAX(step_id)` of each `photo_id`:

```
SELECT
    p.photo_id,
    p.photo_name,
    s.step_id,
    s.step_name
FROM Photo p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        photo_id, MAX(step_id) AS max_step_id
    FROM photoStep
    GROUP BY photo_id
) ps
    ON ps.photo_id = p.photo_id
LEFT JOIN Steps s
    ON s.step_id = ps.max_step_id
```